# Sorting a Collection based on multiple criteria in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, collections

I'm trying to sort by color first and then sort by type.

I'm thinking maybe double foreach loops may not be the answer?

The following is what I have so far.

```
private $color_order = [
    'white',
    'green',
    'purple',
    'blue',     
    ''
];

private $type_order = [
    'diamond',
    'square',
    'circle'
];

private function sortCards($cards, $color_order, $type_order) {
    $collection = collect($cards);

    return $collection->sortBy(function($card) use ($color_order, $type_order) {
        foreach ($type_order as $index => $type) {
            foreach ($color_order as $index => $color) {
                if ($card->card_colors == $color && str_contains($card->card_type, $type)) {
                    return $index;
                }
            }
        }
    })->values();
}
```

Comment: What value does $cards hold?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a macro that will do that for you.  Place the macro in your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`'a `boot()` method:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Collection::macro('sortByMany', function($params) {
            return $this->sortBy(function($item) use ($params) {
                $sort = '';
                foreach($params as $property => $sortOrder) {
                    $key = array_search($item->{$property}, $sortOrder);
                    $sort .= $key === false ? count($sortOrder) + 1 : $key;
                }
                return (int) $sort;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can call it with an array of the sort orders as `['objectProperty' => ['sortorder'], 'otherProp' => ['otherSortOrder']]`.  It will sort the properties in the order they are passed to the method.  In your example it would be:

```
private function sortCards($cards, $color_order, $type_order)
{
    return collect($cards)->sortByMany(['card_colors' => $color_order, 'card_type' => $type_order])->values();
}
```

Comment: It's sorting by color but not by type?

Comment: Can you give a sample data set before and after?

Comment: I just solved it and I posted my solution. Though if your method worked it would have been pretty sweet.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. I know it can be better.

Perhaps someone else can provide a more elegant solution which wouldn't require deeper and deeper if statements?

```
private function sortCards($cards, $color_order, $type_order) {
    return $cards->sort(function($a, $b) use ($color_order, $type_order) {
        $pos_a = array_search($a->card_colors, $color_order);
        $pos_b = array_search($b->card_colors, $color_order);

        if ($pos_a == $pos_b) {
            $pos_a = array_search($a->card_types, $type_order);
            $pos_b = array_search($b->card_types, $type_order);

            if ($pos_a == $pos_b) return 0;
            return $pos_a - $pos_b;
        }
        return $pos_a - $pos_b;
    });
}
```